# MYSQL, not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling my head around days to get rid of this error, but still in vain.
I already search SO before posting the error, but none of them helped me.
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydIrS.png)

[Picture with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVxUI.jpg)

Here is my query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE groups;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I double checked the the table group exist

Edit: Just found out that `groups` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, so is there anyway for me to truncate the table groups

Comment: Yes, it's a reserved word since MySQL 8.0.2, and must be quoted with backticks ( ` ) if used as an identifier.

Comment: Yeah, I just now figured out, can you post this as an answer, I want to mark it as answer

Comment: That's ok, I just gave a pointer so feel free to mark your own answer where you more clearly show what ended up solving it as a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the edit, that `groups` is a reserved word in MySQL, so I had to use the syntax like this

```
TRUNCATE `groups`
```

in order to make it work.